# how to remove "use of old style cast warning"

Tags: c++, casting

I want to remove "use of old style cast" error. Please note that the file I am writing is binary.

I got an warning

```
int temp;
fileID.write((char *)&temp, 1);
```

this does not work

```
fileID.write(static_cast<char *>(&temp), 1);
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? with GCC, you should be able to use `-Wold-style-cast`. For Visual Studio, I think you can do that with the code analyzer tools that they provide, but I have no clue.

Comment: You need to use `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast` since the types are unrelated.

Comment: ... and you are aware that you only write 1 of `sizeof int` bytes?